# Find all strings of a text that have XXX at the EOL

Tags: php

I have a text file with 700,000 lines of login attempts some of which are successful but mainly - not. Here is an example:

```
login attempt 2 to server IP as user_name  - password failed
login  attempt 3 to server IP as user_name  - password failed
login attempt 4 to server IP as user_name  - **successful**
login  attempt 5 to server IP as user_name  - password failed
login attempt 6 to server IP as user_name  - **successful**
```

and so on. How can I delete all lines that do not end with 'successful" word?
pseud-ocode:

1. convert all lines to separate arrays with each word as an array element
2. to write something like this (pseudocode):

   ```
   while(line_number <= 700000)  {

           $all_occurrences .= (end($array) == 'successful') ? whole_line : '';
   }
   ```

so only these will remain:

```
>  login attempt 4 to server IP as user_name  - **successful**  login
> attempt 6 to server IP as user_name  - **successful**
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: if this is just a one time task, it's pretty easy to do via bash prompt on linux.  `grep successful biglogfile.log > ./login.log`

Comment: Thanks Duane. I'd like to sort out the PHP solution despite the fact your answer solves my problem.

Comment: You could use a regex or `strpos` if `successful` would only ever be on the line once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing is to read the files line by line so you don't run into memory constraints.

Solution 1:

```
<?php

$if = '/tmp/login.attempts';
$of = '/tmp/login.attempts.purged';
$ifh = fopen($if, 'r');
$ofh = fopen($of, 'w');

while(($line = fgets($ifh)) !== false) {
    if(preg_match('/successful/', $line)) {
        fwrite($ofh, $line);
    }
}

fclose($ifh);
fclose($ofh);

?>
```

Or if you want to use arrays like your sudo code.

Solution 2:

```
<?php

$if = '/tmp/login.attempts';
$contents = file_get_contents($if);

$all_attempts = explode("\n", $contents);

$successful_attempts = array();

foreach($all_attempts as $attempt) {
    if(preg_match('/successful/', $attempt)) {
        $successful_attempts[] = sprintf("%s", $attempt);
    }
}

// The successful_attempts array contains all your entries
//print_r($successful_attempts);
?>
```

Comment: oh, man. Thank you so much for your time and use of your logic! I still need the last  word of each string to be "successful" but I'll deal with that. You have just helped me to find we were hacked =((( gotta change passwords... Thank you

Comment: @DuaneLortie was correct in his comment; the absolute easiest/best answer, if in a linux/unix environment, is `grep successful /path/to/file.log`

Comment: yes, I agree. but I have reasons of using PHP here and thus,  asked to help me with PHP solution. Nonetheless - once again - thanks DuaneLortie for the suggestion! ))

Comment: To critique myself, the PHP docs for preg_match say the following: "Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() instead as it will be faster."